# Generate PDF with rectangles

Tags: pdf, graphics

What's the easiest way to generate a PDF file with simple filled rectangles on arbitrary locations on the page, given by coordinates?

**Example**: For a given pair of coordinates like `100 50 105 80` I would like to get an A4 PDF with a filled rectangle 5mm wide and 30mm high.

Simple coordinate transformations are no problem to make via script, but what's the best technology to use? I already thought about generating a latex source file with `\rule`, but it seams quite heavyweight when thinking about build automation with docker images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out one easy way to accomplish this with python, using [FPDF's `rect` method](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/rect/index.html):

```py
from fpdf import FPDF

# Prepare PDF generator
pdf = FPDF(orientation = 'L', unit = 'mm', format = 'A4')
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_fill_color(0, 0, 0)

# Draw the rectangle
pdf.rect(x = 100, y = 50, w = 5, h = 30, style = 'F')

# Write to file
pdf.output(filename)
```

Comment: using "`in`" as units would be better because the Typographic Units are proportionate with inches. 1incc = 72points (Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_unit). This will help while extracting the graphics from a PDF